# How do I create a report that tracks changes to a field over a period of time?

Tags: reporting

I am using Sitetracker, and I would like to create a report that runs once per week and captures Jobs that have had a change made to their "Job Status" field over the previous week.

I know how to make a report of all the jobs and their statuses that runs weekly, but how do I only capture the ones that have had a change in a specific field?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  It looks like Sitetracker is a 3rd-party app.  Have you checked with their support?

Comment: unless the vendor product has a field on Job that tracks date of status change; you'll need to run a report on the field history record to detect changes. Assume the vendor has enabled field history tracking for Job

Answer (score 0):

You can try turning on field history tracking in the object manager, then you should be able to make a report of changes on an object for a given field. Make sure you are also allowing reports.
You'll want to pull in new and old value and the edit date.

For example: I want to see all the clients I have that changed their surname within the past year. I turn on field history tracking, I allow reports. Then I make a new report on account history where the old value doesn't equal the new value and the field is surname and the date is this year.

Depending on your goal and your audience, you may also want to look into soql